# NosuchMethodError: the method '[]' was calld on null. Reciever: null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I keep getting this error when i install my app on the some mobile phones, tho it works smoothly on my device

> NosuchMethodError: the method '[]' was calld on null. Reciever: null.
>   Tried calling :

here is a screenshot of the error [image]

here is my code

```
double long;
 Future<ReverseLocation> rLocation() async {
String request =
   "http://**.***.**.**:****/traffic/location/reverse_geocode/?longitude=$long&latitude=$lat";
final response = await http.get(request);
print(request);
print(response.statusCode);
try{

return ReverseLocation.fromRawJson(response.body);
}
catch(e){
return ReverseLocation.fromRawJson(response.body);
}
```

And here is my View

```
@override
_SearchLocationState createState() => _SearchLocationState();
}

class _SearchLocationState extends State<SearchLocation> {
Future<ReverseLocation> locationtwo;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  locationtwo = rLocation();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder(
           // initialData: [],
              future: locationtwo,
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                  return NetworkModal();
                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot
                            .data.entity.addressComponents[0].longName),
                      ],
                    ));
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text("Error ${snapshot.error.toString()}"));

                  }
                  else if(snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Center(child: Text("Null ${snapshot.error}"));
                }
                } {
                  return Center(child: Text("Trying to get Address"));
                }

              }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace if there was any

Comment: try logging snapshot data print(snapshot.data.entity.addressComponents) and see if returns array or null.

Comment: There is none. it works fine on my device, but on sending it over to a team member, they get that error. @JideGuru

Comment: Ohhh You should add internet permission to your manifest then.

Comment: i think problem in this statement  Text(snapshot                           .data.entity.addressComponents[0].longName) here addressComponents get null

Comment: i already did@JideGuru

Comment: Okay. As @KalpeshDabhi said, the issue seems to be that your addressComponents is returning null

Comment: @KalpeshDabhi let me check the response returning from the request

Comment: its not null @KalpeshDabhi

Comment: Ok, Share you error stacktrace, in stacktrace we can find  in which line get error

Comment: @KalpeshDabhi thanks, i was able to rectify it. it seems be an issue between the model and http response

Comment: @JideGuru thanks, i have been able to rectify it